# Subview being clipped

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I added a view controller's view as a subview to a view, and now it keeps getting clipped.

[image]

```
let dayExpenseStorybaord = UIStoryboard(name: "CWDayExpenseStoryboard", bundle: nil)
let dayExpenseVC = dayExpenseStorybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CWDayExpenseView")
(dayExpenseVC as! CWDayExpenseViewController).parentVC = self
childView.addSubview(dayExpenseVC.view)
```

I think this is all the relevant code. Let me know if more needs to be added.

FOLLOW-UP Question

I think I placed the frame and other things correctly, but as you can see the top of the Record Expenses view does not conform to the bottom of the top layout guide. I actually had this in a page view controller, as well, and the same thing happened. What could be causing this issue?

[image]

Comment: There is an [elaborate dance](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers) that must be done in order to implement a custom parent view controller and make a view controller your child and make its view your view's subview, and as far as I can tell you are not doing the dance. Also, I don't see you assigning `dayExpenseVC.view` any `frame`, so you are not making any attempt to control its size or position. So where it appears is going to be pretty much random.

Answer (score 0):

You to either set the `frame` and [`autoResizingMask`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622559-autoresizingmask) and `dayExpenseVC.view` or set [`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco) to `false` and add the necessary constraints.

Also, don't forget to call [`addChildViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621394-addchildviewcontroller) and [`didMove(toParentViewController:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621405-didmove) when you're done adding the view, in order to satisfy the view controller containment requirements. By the way, if you do that, that will result in [`parent`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621362-parent) being set, obviating the need for your own `parentVC` property.

```
let dayExpenseVC = dayExpenseStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CWDayExpenseView") as! CWDayExpenseViewController
addChildViewController(dayExpenseVC)
// dayExpenseVC.parentVC = self
dayExpenseVC.view.frame = ... 
childView.addSubview(dayExpenseVC.view)
dayExpenseVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```